# Meteor - I have error and I can`t debug it

Tags: javascript, meteor, typeerror, meteor-blaze

I have an error in meteor project - like that:

```
TypeError: callbacks[i].call is not a function
    at template.js:116
    at Function.Template._withTemplateInstanceFunc (template.js:437)
    at fireCallbacks (template.js:112)
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (template.js:205)
    at view.js:104
    at Object.Blaze._withCurrentView (view.js:523)
    at view.js:103
    at Object.Tracker._runFlush (tracker.js:468)
    at onGlobalMessage (setimmediate.js:102)
```

Don you have any idea for that?

Addition: 
1) at template.js:116

```js
var fireCallbacks = function (callbacks, template) {
  Template._withTemplateInstanceFunc(
    function () { return template; },
    function () {
      for (var i = 0, N = callbacks.length; i < N; i++) {
        callbacks[i].call(template);
      }
    });
};
```

Comment: have you tried at least log what is inside `callbacks[i]`?

Comment: You're probably forgetting to pass a callback somewhere. Something's ending up in Meteor's callback array that's not a function. Without seeing your code, it's hard to know.

Comment: Where is *your* code? Without it there is no indication of what triggered it.

Answer (score 4):

I found the problem!
It was because that:

```js
Template.user_lesson.onRendered({});
```

And should be like that:

```js
Template.user_lesson.onRendered(function(){});
```

I didn`t use that in parent template and had an error. 
Thanks!